# Including Rnw files within a package

Tags: r, package, knitr

I am writing a package and the sole purpose of this package is to create reports. I am using `knit` to generate the reports from a .Rnw file. This all happens within a function in the package. e.g.

```
create_report <- function(data) {
  knit2pdf(from = "myreport.Rnw", to = "myreport.tex")
  # The Rnw in the knit2pdf function uses the data passed to this function
}
```

My question is simple. Where within my package folders do I store the .Rnw file? Currently my package has the following folders:

1. .Rproj.user
2. data
3. man
4. R

I am just not sure where my Rnw scripts should go? Do I need another folder called LaTeX for example? This is like having a separate folder for C++ scripts, for example.

Note, I am not looking to create a vignette. I know how to do this. This package is used to do some data manipulation and then generate a report on the data.

I have tried to lay everything out as clearly as I can as some questions I have asked on here before have been misinterpreted. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: WRE describes how subfolders in inst/ will be copied to the top-level when installing your package. You could therefore place your templates (that's how I interpret your question) in inst/latex, and the package user could access them with `system.file`.

Comment: Ok I am still learning about package development as I go, so I will check out the .Rproj.user.

Who is WRE? Sorry.

I will try placing them in inst/latex. I tried placing them in inst however system.file cannot find them after building the package...they are indeed templates however.

Comment: Writing R Extensions. You really ought to read it if you're writing a package.

Comment: I've read it. But I still don't understand. I am trying to use `system.file()` but it just returns `""`. It can't find the inst folder within my package (this is after I have installed it and `library` has been ran.

Comment: It has been installing somewhere else. The installed package doesn't include the inst folder. I understand now!

Comment: yes. In my cda package, I use [inst/povray](https://github.com/baptiste/cda/tree/master/inst/povray), which gets copied at the top-level upon installation, and I access it with `system.file("povray", package = "cda")`.

Comment: note that `.Rproj.user` should probably be excluded in `.Rbuildignore` (I made a typo earlier)

Comment: Ah excellent. Thanks for your help :) So my function above will actually become something like: `knit2pdf(input = system.file("mytemplate.Rnw", output = "mypathinput.tex")`. Is this correct? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: The .Rproj.user is indeed excluded from the built package. The built package has different folders to the ones I listed. The ones I listed are from the unbuilt package, if that makes sense?

Comment: You should probably first make a copy of the template file to a local folder (e.g. a temporary folder); knitting the file directly from the library seems wrong (and might get into permission problems).

Comment: Ok. The main reason that I wanted it within the package was to avoid sending people multiple files. I can envisage people installing the latest version of the package but not copying the latest Rnw file and errors will start to occur. Whereas if the Rnw file is in the package, then everything will always be up to date when they update the package.

Comment: you could also save the template as a text string in data/, and use `knit(text=...)`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I haven't come across that one. Thank you for your help @baptiste, I really do appreciate this one. I'm surprised there have been so few questions around this online. Or maybe I've just been slow to get it...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question:
Include the .Rnw files in `./pkgname/inst/latex` then when you build the package, the `./latex` folder will go to the root level of the package. You can then extract the .Rnw files using `system.file("latex", "mytemplate.Rnw", package = "pkgname")`.